# Disable form auto submit on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, form-submit, forms

I have a HTML form where I use several buttons. The problem is that no matter which button I  click, the form will get submitted even if the button is not of type "submit". e.g. Buttons like :`<button>Click to do something</button>`, result in form submission.

It's quite painful to do an `e.preventDefault()` for each one of these buttons.

I use jQuery and jQuery UI and the website is in HTML5.

Is there a way to disable this automatic behavior?

Answer (score 599, accepted):

Buttons like `<button>Click to do something</button>` **are** submit buttons.

Set `type="button"` to change that. `type="submit"` is the default (as [specified by the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)):

> The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.

Answer (score 23):

You could just try using **return false** (return false overrides default behaviour on every DOM element) like that :

```
myform.onsubmit = function ()
{ 
  // do what you want
  return false
}
```

and then submit your form using myform.submit()

or alternatively :

```
mybutton.onclick = function () 
{
   // do what you want
   return false
}
```

Also, if you use `type="button"` your form will not be submitted.

Answer (score 19):

`<button>`'s are in fact submit buttons, they have no other main functionality. You will have to set the type to button.
But if you bind your event handler like below, you target all buttons and do not have to do it manually for each button!

```
$('form button').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It's `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Beautiful, I came here to post the same thing

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add directly  to  input    as attribute, use this

```
 onclick="return false;" 

<input id = "btnPlay" type="button" onclick="return false;" value="play" />
```

this will prevent form submit behaviour

Answer (score -2):

another one:

```
if(this.checkValidity() == false) {

                $(this).addClass('was-validated');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Like `mas-designs` said, call `preventDefault()`. You can call it on the form itself. Here's a function that does this for all forms, vanilla JS.

```
function forms_ini(){
  for(var form of document.getElementsByTagName('form')){
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault()
    })
  }
}
```