# JSP + JavaScript + Servlet Unexpected Results

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a form on a jsp which calls a javascript function which latter calls a servlet. However the code mention below works once in while and when the code does reach the servlet the parameters return null. Also its really bizarre but it jumps between The doGet and doPost method even though i specify "POST". Can someone assist me with the correction.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {

        var dataf = 'email=' + $('#email').val()
                + '&password=' + $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/RetailerGui/loginServlet",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataf,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);

            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

JSP FORM:

```
              <form id="newsletter" method="POST">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="bg">
                      Email:<input type="text" id="email">
                    </div>
                     <div class="bg">
                      Password:<input type="password" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <button class="my_button" name="login" >login</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

SERVLET "loginServlet":

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
       String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String loginResult = login(email,password);
        System.out.println("EMAIL:" +email);
        System.out.println("PASSWORD:" +password);
        System.out.println("IM INSIDE GET!!!!");
        response.getWriter().write(loginResult);

    }

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String loginResult = login(email,password);
    System.out.println("IM INSIDE POST!!!!");
    response.getWriter().write(loginResult);
}
```

If any other information is required please let me know. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: aren't you missing an action="" parameter?

Comment: Your `<button>` should be made `type=button` to prevent its default action from being the form submission. Also you need to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the username and password strings.

Comment: The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) say that `$().ready( handler )` is not recommended. Could this be a factor? The document seems to contradict itself by stating explicitly that "the selector can be omitted".

Comment: There are several problems with your code. You should actually use `<input type="submit" ...>` instead of `<button>` and also, rather than having an onclick handler attached to the button, use the `onsubmit` property of the form itself. If the handler returns `false`, the form submission is cancelled, thus your handler can effectively override the default form behaviour. Other than that, I have to admit that I did not take a look deep enough to spot the exact cause.

Comment: @Pointy,@JimmyM so i added type=button and removed $().ready( handler ) now the button seems to be inactive and it is not reaching the js funtion at all.

Comment: You should not have removed the "ready" handler. @Powerslave there's no reason to use `<input type=submit>` if he's going to disable the native functionality anyway; a `<button>` is fine.

Comment: @JimmyM you're misrepresenting that advice.  It's not about avoiding "ready" handlers entirely; it's saying that there's no need to write it that way when `$(function() { ... })` means exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JimmyM sorry misunderstood.

Comment: @Pointy keeping the "ready" handler or not still makes the button response inactive for some reason with type="button"

Comment: Are you getting errors in the developer console? Can you tell whether the HTTP request is being made with appropriate arguments?  What do you see from the server side?

Comment: So i added a Alert("CLICKED"); within the button function in the js so with removing the "ready" handler it is not displayed, however keeping the "ready" handler with alert is displayed, for the server side console does not display anything, however sometimes when it does reach the console no error message just the email and password variables are assigned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution through this site, thank you for the help everyone!
   http://coderlearner.com/Java_Servlet_doGet_Ajax_JSON#LoginJSON.java

Answer (score 0):

Three points here,

2. In the html, your button will end up submitting your form to the current url (Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824845/1304559)

   > Set type="button" to change that. type="submit" is the default (as specified by the HTML recommendation).
3. In the html, `<form>`, add `onsubmit="return false"`. Just to be entirely safe that it does not post back to the current url.
4. One question - what does `processRequest` do in your servlet code?