# Inserting the value in form's textfield onclick of a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 //This is a Js Calculator Code  
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <script>
  function show(n) {
    document.calform.screen.value = document.calform.screen.value + n;
  }
  function operation(op) {
    document.calform.screen.value = document.calform.screen.value + op;
  }
  function equals() {
    document.calform.screen.value=eval(document.calform.screen.value);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <form name="calform" style="width:200px;" method="post">
      <fieldset border="1px">
        <legend> Calculator</legend>
        <input type="text" name="screen" /><br/><br/>
        <button onclick="show('7')">7</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">8</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">9</button>
        <button onclick="operation('+')">+</button><br/>
        <button onclick="show('7')">4</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">5</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">6</button>
        <button onclick="operation('-')">-</button><br/>
        <button onclick="show('7')">3</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">2</button>
        <button onclick="show('7')">1</button>
        <button onclick="operation('*')">*</button><br/>
        <button onclick="operation('/')">/</button>
        <button onclick="operation('%')">%</button>
        <button onclick="">=</button>
        <button onclick="">C</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that it insert the value in the form's textfield on   onclick event of a button but the value doesn't hold in the textfield after click event........ Kindly leave your suggestions to resolve this issue..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the value doesn't hold in the textfield after click event". Can you help to clarify?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the form submits after clicking any button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms). Also see [Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form), [HTML button to NOT submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form), [Disable form auto submit on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what @showdev said:  the form submits on each button click.  As soon as it submits, the field disappears.  What you need to do is have `type="button"` in your html, so it would look like this:  `<button type="button" onclick="show('7')">7</button>`