# Select all checkboxes in django template

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using the following code to 'select all' and 'clear' the checkboxes of my django form in the django template.

```
 <form id="inv_form" method="post" action="{% url 'inventory:create_inventory' %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Inventory" />
     <a href="{% url 'user:dashboard' %}">Cancel</a>
     <button onclick="select_all()">Select All</button>
     <button onclick="deselect_all()">Clear</button>
  </form>

  function select_all()  {
     $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
  }

  function deselect_all()  {
     $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
  }
```

The problem is the form is getting automatically posted if I press 'check all' button. Same in case of 'clear' button.

So I tried adding preventDefault() to my form submit event.

```
  $("#inv_form").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Now the original problem has been solved, but the submit doesn't works even on clicking at all.

How to make the check all button work without auto posting the django form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution here. 
[** stack overflow: disable auto-submit on button click **](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click)
It explains that by html5 default a button is type="submit". The solution to the above problem is explained below.

```
<button type="button" onclick="select_all()">Select All</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably hate to unbind submit, then you can submit the form.

```
$('some_form').unbind('submit').submit()
```

This approach should cancel `prevenDefault` so you can submit the form.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly to place it.