# How to stop page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax jquery to stop my page from reloading whenever the button is pressed, but the page is still reloading after I implemented it.

This is just a test system for "liking" a post.

//foreach loop that echos out row

```
foreach($dbData as $post){
  <p id="likecount" class = "likecount"> </p>
     <p>
     <form method="post" id="liketest" class="redirect" >
     <button type="submit" id="like" name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'">
         <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
     </button>
     </form>
     </p>
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#like').focus();
            $('#like').keypress(function(event) {
                var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (key == 13) {
                    var info = $('#like').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: {like: info},
                        success: function(status) {
                            $('#likecount').append(status);
                            $('#like').val('');
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    echo '<h1>'.$_POST['like'];
}
?>
```

I expect it to not reload the page but the actual output is the page still reloading once the button is clicked.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like your code might generate duplicate element IDs. Note that [IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) "must be unique in the whole document".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent page from reloading after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634088/how-to-prevent-page-from-reloading-after-form-submit-jquery). Also see [Prevent page from refreshing after an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362821/prevent-page-from-refreshing-after-an-ajax-call) and [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`event.preventDefault()`

after

`$('#like').keypress(function(event) {`

to stop reloading the page.

Comment: The page still reloads :/

Comment: You can use class instead of id because id is unique for all the elements of DOM. and replace the line " <button type="submit" id="like" name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'"> ", by <button type="submit" class="like" name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'"> " and javascript should be "$('.like').keypress(function(event) {" and then use event.preventDefault(); and replace the line " var info = $('#like').val(); " by var info = $(this).val();

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code like this.

```
<form method="post" id="liketest" class="redirect" onSubmit="return false;">
```

Then, you must have to send form data with ajax.
It's the best way to send a post request without page reload.

Comment: Why do we insist on using inline JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
event.preventDefault();
```

after this

```
$('#like').keypress(function(event) {
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: The page still reloads.

Comment: change button type submit to button <button type="button" id="like" name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'">
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
 </button>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change form's default behaviour so just add `onsubmit="return false"`:

```
<form onsubmit="return false"></form>
```

`return false` will prevent `form` submit

Comment: Why do we insist on using inline JavaScript?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard If in case `jQuery.js ` is not loaded & just form is loaded then inline JavaScript will prevent form from submitting.

Comment: You do not need inline JavaScript even when you're using VanillaJS.

Comment: But there is no difference between VanillaJS & JS, am I right?

Comment: LOL. Yes - VanillaJS *is just* JS. And you do not need to use it inline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197887/discussion-between-rk003-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: For maintainability using inline JavaScript should not be done. You should seek to separate code from markup. Use a handler to capture the click, then use `preventDefault()`