# (ngSubmit) is called when press (click) button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two buttons on my Angular2 Form Component. The button are doing their own functionalities.

1. Button Submit : Which is submit all the values to the API.
2. Button Add. : Which is push an object to an array.

The two methods are here...

```
onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
this.model.service_requests = this.modelJobServices;
this.onCreateJob();
}

addJobService(modelJobService :Jobservice){
let modelJobServiceLocal = new Jobservice(modelJobService.service_id,modelJobService.service_note,modelJobService.status)
this.modelJobServices.push(modelJobServiceLocal);
}
```

My Component.html structure is as below

```
<form #jobRegistrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
......
......
......
<button class="flat btn-primary form-control" id="btn_add" (click)="addJobService(modelJobService)"> ADD SERVICE </button>
....
....
....
<button (submit)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!jobRegistrationForm.form.valid" class="flat form-control col-md-4 btn-primary">{{BUTTON_TEXT}}</button>
```

when I press the `(click)` button the form is submitted to the API call. But I did not call the `onSubmit()` on the `(click)` button event

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate?) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Buttons inside a form become a `type="submit"` by default.

Make them plain buttons explicitly:

```
<button type="button"
```

Comment: This is madness!! :-p 
Thanks a lot! I wouldn't have guessed that.
Do you know why Angular does this? For me it would be way cleaner if ngSubmit was only called for type="submit" buttons.

Comment: So outrageously simple, yet so hard to find! Thank you!

Comment: @Zaphoid This is not a choice made by Angular: A button's type always defaults to "submit" unless otherwise specified, even in vanilla javascript. See also [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click). I imagine it would be difficult and confusing for Angular to override this behavior.

Answer (score 7):

As per W3 spec the default value for attribute **type** inside button is submit.

ie `<button> == <button type="submit">`

If you dont want the ngSubmit event to get triggered set the attribute **type** to button.

`<button type="button">`

Or use $event.preventDefault().

`<button (click)="addJobService(modelJobService); $event.preventDefault()"`

Answer (score 2):

inside form when (**ngSubmit**) is placed it always waits for 2 things.

1. Is the Form is valid? it checks whether all the *required* input is
   filled.
2. waits for any *event* to trigger the (**ngsubmit**) like
   button click(in which type is not mentioned or type is mentioned as
   submit) or enter in any input field.

Answer (score 1):

In html

```
<form  #myForm="ngForm">
</form>

<button (click)="send()"></button>
```

In Controller

> @ViewChild('myForm') ngForm: NgForm;
>
> send() { this.ngForm.ngSubmit.emit(); }