# How to get country code with ng-intl-tel-input directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intl-tel-input, angularjs-3rd-party

### How to get country code from input type in Angularjs

I am new in Angularjs, right now I have dropdown of country code + input type text (for mobile number), after a click on submit button, I am getting mobile number successfully but how can I get the country code as well? Here is my HTML code

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" 
       ng-model="updating.phone" ng-intl-tel-input numbers-only
       data-selected-country="selected.country" style="width:100%;">
```

Here is my script code

```
function getviewed()
{
    var form = new FormData();
    var numbr = document.getElementById('tel').value;
 }
```

### Editors note:

The GitHub for the [ng-intl-tel-input](http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/) directive is https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input

Comment: Share country code html and js

Comment: You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968069/ngsubmit-is-called-when-press-click-button

Comment: Looks like it is bound to `selected.country`

Comment: BTW if you are not constrained to an existing platform I would strongly recommend learning [angular 7](https://angular.io) (latest as of now) instead as angularjs entered [LTS last year](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Igor If one wants to learn a framework that is not End-of-Life, there are better choices than Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.element("#tel").intlTelInput.getSelectedCountryData()
```