# How to refresh a page without form submitting?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, form-submit, page-refresh

I build a page to modify a product. So I have a form with product data.

I added a button that, when we click on it, does some stuff in Ajax. At the end of the treatment, **I just want to refresh my page** (because I display a flash message of confirmation). In short, I just want to show my page (not submit it).

**This treatment is completely something else than modifying product data.**

I tried these different solution :

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
// or
window.location.reload(true);
// or
window.location = window.location.href;
// or
window.location.href = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
// or
location.reload();
```

Everytime, **it submits my form and my product is updated** !!

But I don't send any post data. I just want to do the same action than if I push F5 on my keyboard = show my form (not submit it).

Any idea ?

### **EDIT**

Don't forget to add `<button type="button" ...` or it's a **submit button** by default.

Rookie mistake...

Another solution is to display the confirmation message with jQuery without refreshing the page.

Comment: Seems like showing your message in a modern way would be easier (and a better UX).

Comment: What type does your button have?

Comment: _"At the end of the treatment, I just want to refresh my page (because I display a flash message of confirmation)"_ ... you mean Adobe Flash? Please tell me it's not that. But anyway, regardless of how you've implemented it, you don't need to refresh in order to display a message...just use some JavaScript (to either display some HTML which looks like a popup box, or even just use `alert()`).

Comment: As to why refreshing submits your form, it's not clear without seeing more code...but possibly your form's default action is GET? Although AFAIK a reload still shouldn't cause any form to submit....unless I'm wrong, that sounds pretty strange to me

Comment: @isherwood & @ADyson : Yes I should display my message with jQuery, maybe it's better... I forgot to add `type="button"` in my `button` tag. It seems that if we don't add this, it's a submit button by default. Sorry, it was Friday and I was tired lol. Rookie mistake... Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable form auto submit on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add `<button type="button"` ... or it's a **submit button** by default.

Rookie mistake...

Another solution is to display the confirmation message with jQuery without refreshing the page.

Answer (score -1):

Your form may be submitting because the default type for a button is `submit`. Try changing it to `button`.