# Why my JavaScript code always returns "Not Found"?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to do something like a game where the users have 3 attempts to guess what number is randomly generated by the code.

The problem is, every time I click on the button, it returns a "Not Found" page.

```js
    var numeroSecreto = parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
    var tentativas = 3
    
    function funcao(){
      var numero=document.getElementById("entrada").value;
      
     while (tentativas > 0) {
    
    if (numeroSecreto == numero) {
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="Acertou";
    break
    } else if (numero > numeroSecreto) {
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="O número secreto é menor";
    tentativas = tentativas - 1
    } else if (numero < numeroSecreto) {
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML= "O número secreto é maior";
    tentativas = tentativas - 1
    }
    }
    if (numero != numeroSecreto) {
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="Suas tentativas acabaram o número era: " + numeroSecreto; 
    }}
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
        <body>
          <div = "caixa">
            <form>
              Digite um número inteiro de 0 a 10:
              <input id="entrada">
              <button id="botao" onclick="funcao()">Ir</button>
              <div id="saida"></div>
           </div>   
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable form auto submit on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824808/disable-form-auto-submit-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking a button inside a `form` which will submit the form by default and redirect to a page. To prevent that, you can make the button as `type="button"` so that it doesn't submit the form.

```js
var numeroSecreto = parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
var tentativas = 3

function funcao(){
  var numero=document.getElementById("entrada").value;
  
 while (tentativas > 0) {

if (numeroSecreto == numero) {
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="Acertou";
break
} else if (numero > numeroSecreto) {
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="O número secreto é menor";
tentativas = tentativas - 1
} else if (numero < numeroSecreto) {
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML= "O número secreto é maior";
tentativas = tentativas - 1
}
}
if (numero != numeroSecreto) {
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML="Suas tentativas acabaram o número era: " + numeroSecreto; 
}}
```

```html
<div = "caixa">
        <form>
          Digite um número inteiro de 0 a 10:
          <input id="entrada">
          <button id="botao" type="button" onclick="funcao()">Ir</button>
          <div id="saida"></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Ohhh... I really didnt know that. Thanks! Now my "Not found" problem is solved. But the code still don't work. Anyway, thanks! Now I'm going to try to solve this ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you don't define a `type` attribute for the button tag, [the browser does it for you](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp). Different browsers may have different default values, but the browsers you're using clearly is setting it to `type="submit"`. This means, the moment you click it, it tries to submit the form data, but since the form data isn't going anywhere besides your JavaScript code, you get this `Not Found` error. What you want to do is this: `type="button"`. Now it'll work as intended, since it's now just a button and the browser won't assume anything about what it should do.

Btw, brotip: if you're not changing the HTML code explicitly, avoid using `innerHTML`, because it can cause serious accidents. Use `innerText` instead because it won't mess with the tag.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I didnt know that and I made the changes you recommended about innerHTML. Is more a case of copy/past, is better for me read the documentation before do this mistakes, lol.